# Maintaining a pop up after submitting the page

Tags: magento, popup

My client is using [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), and after clicking the submit button, the form submits to the controller and then the same page reloads. What he asked me is once he clicks on the submit button he wants a popup displayed. So I used a div with a disabled background as a popup in a dynamic way (JavaScript), but since the button is "submitting", the page refreshes and I lose the popup, so is it possible to keep that div displayed even after submitting?

Comment: Is this something that could be submitted via AJAX? That would avoid leaving the page and so preserve the state.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_selector').submit(function(){
        showDialog();
        //stop submit
        return false;
    });
    $('#dialog_button_selector').click(function(){
        //submit form
        $('#form_selector').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i do not want to hold the submission until i click on the popup , it is not a confirmation popup, This is a ecommerce website the popup shows details about the product the client did purchase plus some links to other pages, I need that submission to happen in order to add the product to the cart and i want to maintain the popup even after submission, Like if the website is disabled just that div popup is actif.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Magneto, but generally speaking, couldn't you look for a form submit in the controller when the page reloads and call for the popup, if true?

Comment: I wish i could find the controller! i would  delete that redirect instruction at once! I also not into frameworks... and this MVC is just hard to follow. Ive tried storing values on Session and then when page reloads i display the DIV with the data on the session, but i came across another problem , some data were client side , i couldnt store them to the session and i could not post them as i told you , didnt want to mess with magento core. It sounds complicated/stupid , but what ive been trying to do or what i have in my mind is a div displaying before/after submission.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use slide panel instead of pop-up panel?

For instance, check `isLoggedin` function of Magento :

```
<?php
if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
    echo "Welcome!";
} else {
    echo "Please log in.";
}
?>
```

if customer is logged, show necessary information of customer inside the slide panel.

If you want just one time show this panel, try to event observer methods of magento :

app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php

Event names :

- customer_login
- customer_session_init

For jQuery Sliding Panel, you can use jqEasy which is supporting `showOnLoad` property.

[jqEasy](http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-sliding-info-panel-plugin/)

Comment: The popup doesnt show after the customer logs in, but after he clicks on "Add a product". and it is just a div inside the same page. its purpose is to display details about the product purchased, Name , Price and quantity , plus a couple of links. So oncee the client clicks on the button, form sunmits and i lose that popup since the controller redirects to some other page.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't want to hold submission of the page, you basically need to echo the popup *after* the page is submitted. So, using some generic event (`catalog_product_add_to_cart_after`), add a session variable like this:

```
public function observer($event) {
    Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->setNeedsCartPopup(true);
}
```

Then, in your template, you can check for the existence of this variable to show your popup:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($session->getNeedsCartPopup()) {
    $session->->setNeedsCartPopup(false);
    // echo HTML to display popup as the page loads
}
```

This is not tested code, but it should give you the gist of how to capture the event and respond to it in the template. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe